# Translating "Fax" in the backend

Tags: magento-2.2.5, translate

I want to rename "**Fax**" to "**Mobile**" on the backend (Create New Order page). I assumed this could be achieved by updating my `en_GB.csv` file in my child theme.

> Assembling the preceding pt_BR.csv files across all modules and the current theme results in a Portuguese translation of the entire application area (storefront or the Admin). - [Magento Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html)

However, this does not appear to have any affect. Is this label actually translatable? I prefer not override a file for something so trivial.

*Note: My translation file works fine for everything else and cache is currently disabled. So I know it's nothing like that.*

Answer (score 0):

If you change just only translation that will not be so obvious to developers after you to find this field in database.
So the right way is to make another field for mobile and hide this one if you don't need it.